# error: invalid operand. ASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

nasm gives the following error message:

```
error: invalid operand.
MOV $16731,%ebx
```

the code:

```
MOV $16731,%ebx
MOV $19508,%eax
MOV $1436,%ecx
CMP %eax,%ebx
JL L1
JMP L2
L1:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
ADD %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
SUB %ecx,%eax
JMP L3
L2:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
SUB %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
ADD %ecx,%eax
L3:
NOP
```

AT&T syntax by default 
im having some trouble figuring it out. What's the value of %eax when the last instruction (the NOP) runs?
Thanks

Comment: `nasm` doesn't do at&t, you need to rewrite to intel or use gnu assembler (`as`) or something that does understand at&t. It's also easy to trace these few instructions by hand (which is presumably what you are expected to do, to show that you understand the code).

Comment: How to convert this code to intel ? there is converter from at&t to intel ? ,

Comment: Swap all operands, remove all `$` and `%` characters.

Comment: <code>
MOV ebx,13761
MOV eax,19508
MOV eax,80591
MOV ecx,1436
MOV ecx,6341
CMP eax,ebx
JL L1
JMP L2
L1:
IMUL eax,ebx
ADD eax,ebx
MOV ebx,eax
SUB ecx,eax
JMP L3
L2:
IMUL eax,ebx
SUB eax,ebx
MOV ebx,eax
ADD ecx,eax
L3:
NOP
</code>
f╗┴5

Comment: You didn't swap the operands. You should edit your question instead of commenting.